# Need the cell reference for a cell with unknown row and known column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-match

I am trying take an `ID` in `ColumnX` and verify find an occurrence of this `ID` in `columnY` using the `MATCH()` function. This function returns a row number of the match. I now need to take the row number and combine it with a `ColumnZ` in order to make a reference to a value where I later run a comparison on this value.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
IF(EXACT(MATCH(X:X, Y:Y, 0), Z:Z), "Y", "N")
```

The bug in this code is where I am passing the parameters into the `EXACT` function. It wants two strings (i.e. cell values), only the `Z:Z` statement correctly satisfies this, is there anyway to achieve something like this:

```
IF(EXACT(("Z" + MATCH(X:X, Y:Y, 0)), Z:Z), "Y", "N")
```

I am simply trying to create a cell reference from a known Column number (what I don't know how to do) and an unknown row number (produced by the `MATCH` function).

I have already tried using the `Vlookup` function and it does not produce the desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to use **INDIRECT**?

I believe that's the function you might need. You'll need to check now *where* you need to add it. I'd guess it's here:

```
=IF(EXACT(INDIRECT("Z" & MATCH(X:X, Y:Y, 0)), Z:Z), "Y", "N")
```

Rgds

Answer (score 1):

Mike,

If I understand your needs, the following will work.  It says, "find the row in column Y that matches the value in X1 and return the value at that row in column Z":

```
=INDEX(Z:Z,MATCH(X1,Y:Y,0))
```

The 0 argument in the Match function specifies an exact match, meaning that column Y doesn't need to be sorted (similar to the optional False argument in VLookup).